# Don't include .Where() if variable is null ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have this function:

```
        public List<PostIndexResponse> GetPosts(string search, int? categoryId)
        {
            var currentUserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId() ?? "";
            var srch = search ?? "";
            var posts = _set.Where(x => x.PersonId.Contains(currentUserId) && x.Description.Contains(srch) && x.CategoryId == categoryId).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn)).ToList();
            return posts;
        }
```

I want to have `x.CategoryId == categoryId` only if `categoryId` is not null. How do I do this without having an if else condition and creating another query based if it is null or not?

Comment: .Where(x => (categoryId == null || x.CategoryId == categoryId))

Comment: If this is Entity Framework core (please add a version tag), then the suggestion above works. In EF6 it will always become part of the SQL query which is less optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would break it up in to a couple lines something like this (UNTESTED)...

This allows you to conditionally filter on `categoryId` and I think it's cleaner and more maintainable than attempting to cram it all in to a single expression. No need to create 2 overlapping expressions

```
public List<PostIndexResponse> GetPosts(string search, int? categoryId)
{
    var currentUserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId() ?? "";
    var srch = search ?? "";

    var query = _set.Where(x => x.PersonId.Contains(currentUserId) && x.Description.Contains(srch));

    if (categoryId.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId);

    var posts = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn)).ToList();
    return posts;
}
```

The other option is to replace `x.CategoryId == categoryId` with

```
(categoryId == null || x.CategoryId == categoryId)
```

But that expression is already getting long and difficult to maintain.

Comment: @HamidIsrafilov No, if `categoryId` is null then that condition is false and the whole where expression evaluates to false rather than ignoring the condition completely.